# Any SVG animation tools out there?

Tags: svg

I'd like to create some animations using SVG. Are there any tools out there similar to flash, where I'd get a stage and a timeline where I can manipulate objects over time, then play them back?

Thanks

Comment: There is a commercial tool created exactly for that purpose: https://aphalina.com/

Answer (score 6):

There is the similar question at [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/171677/are-there-programs-to-create-and-edit-svg-animations). The best answer there is the link to the [Inkspace wiki page](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Animation-%28Timeline%29) with a list of existing animating programs.

It's looks like [Adobe Edge Animate](http://html.adobe.com/edge/animate/) is the program that should fill the gap of SVG-animating programs with nice GUI, but now it doesn't look very helpful for my opinion. I'm looking forward to see that Adobe combine [Snapsvg](http://snapsvg.io) with Edge Animate.

Comment: Development for Adobe Edge Animate has stoped since Nov/2015. See: [adobe edge product page](https://www.adobe.com/products/edge-animate.html). This is an additional quote from the site: " Note:

Only Creative Cloud subscribers with a paid All Apps membership are entitled to download and install apps no longer in development. Such apps aren't available to users with a trial membership."

Answer (score 2):

[Synfig studio](http://synfig.org/) with the [SVG export plugin](http://synfig.org/wiki/Sif2svg).

Answer (score 1):

with Blender, since integration of Freestyle, you can animate your 3D models, and then, thanks to freestyle in scripting mode, write python modules that can be used to output any kind of documented vector format.
SVG has already some interesting implementation, you can have a look for example at this repository: https://github.com/hvfrancesco/freestylesvg

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: done, added quick description